# Vite + React Environment for CI/CD without .env files

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, vite

Dependencies:

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.4.2",
    "axios": "^1.6.2",
    "bulma": "^0.9.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.21.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-plotly.js": "^2.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.3.2",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "postcss-nested": "^6.0.1",
    "vite": "^5.0.4",
    "vite-aliases": "^0.11.3",
    "vite-plugin-svgr": "^4.2.0"
  }
```

I have a React app tooled by Vite that runs locally with values taken from a `.env` file. These all start with `VITE_` and are retrieved in the code via `import.meta.env.VITE_SOME_NAME`. This works perfectly well in development.

In order to deploy this, I need to access these same variables from the OS environment. Once in the deployed environment, I need to be able to run `npm run build` and have the values properly replaced, again without resorting to a `.env` file. This has been impossible, as apparently Vite stopped reading the environment around version 1.

My current solution is to use a "fake" `.env.production` whose values for the variables are just magic strings with environment variable names and then, after building it on the server, and still in deployment, I run a script that:

1. gets the values from the OS environment;
2. finds the magic strings in the built JS code;
3. replaces the magic strings with the values in the environment.

Is there any chance I could do this directly with `npm run build` *without* pouring actual values into `.env.production`? Better, still: is this possible without any `.env.production` at all, fake or real? Like Vite actually going for the values in the OS?

Please refrain from mentioning the `.env.production` option with actual values in it. This is off the table, as we don't want any secrets on file. The idea is to pass these to the OS environment either via CI/CD variables, or Ansible scripting.

I know web apps can't read from the OS environment. What I'm asking is for a way for a Docker container to pull a repo and run `npm run build` on it, using OS Environment variables *instead* of `.env` files. I am likewise aware of the fact that whatever goes into JS cannot be hidden.

Comment: As far as I can tell in Vite 5 _does_ pull `VITE_` from the environment, I don't have a `.env` file at all and it's showing up in the build. Alternatively there are methods that don't rely on your React tooling at all, llike SSI (Vite doesn't strip the include comments from HTML) - https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Do your env variables not in the `.env` file not get recognized by Vite when building? As long as they start with `VITE_` they should be included. especially if they're set in the OS before running the build command.